# Braintree Node.js - get expired credit cards

Tags: node.js, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I need to get a list of expiring credit cards.

Looking thru the docs, I found this: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/credit-card/expiring-between/node

Docs say: `Returns a collection of CreditCard objects that expire between the specified dates.`

So I created a sample code for this.

```
gateway.creditCard.expiringBetween(before, after, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('I have an error', { err });
    }
    console.log('results', { result });
  });
```

The result I'm getting is the following:

```
results { result:
   SearchResponse {
     pagingFunction:
      CreditCardGateway { gateway: [BraintreeGateway], config: [Config] },
     ids: [ 'jx7sds', 'grp387' ],
     pageSize: 50,
     stream:
      SearchResponseStream {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        domain: [Domain],
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        searchResponse: [Circular],
        currentItem: 0,
        currentOffset: 0,
        bufferedResults: [] },
     success: true } }
```

I see I'm getting an array of Credit Card `Ids`.

If I iterate over those Ids and do a `gateway.creditCard.find` I can find information for those Credit Cards.

However, I'm confused by the docs stating that I should be getting the Credit Card objects in the initial response.

It looks like an overkill to go and find each CC individually when I should have gotten them in the first place. I must be doing something wrong.

Since I've seen some BT devs here at SO I thought I might ask the community.

Has someone done this before and could share some code snippet or point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just asked Braintree support if the doc is correct and got the following anwer:

> You are correct that the result returns an array of the payment
>   method tokens (IDs). Thanks for the call out. We will discuss this
>   further with our documentation team.

They also said that iterating over the ids is the way to go.